# JSX Interpolation not showing on mobile browser

Tags: reactjs

I was just running a test on jsx interpolation. I use CRA to create a react app and inserted simple data. The code runs on desktop browser but on my mobile chrome/safari browser, it is not displaying. How can I show this on the mobile web browser? Am i missing anything here.
Thanks.

Edit: I've tried using https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1 it is displaying the output however not with own API. Both returning object.
Tested with adding a button to update state it is able to display. Just that the first initial load, it is missing from mobile browser(chrome, safari).
Any thoughts?

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h2>React App</h2>
      <Test />
      <Test />
    </div>
  );
}


On Test component
export const Test = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('http://localhost:5000/v1/auth')
      .then((data) => {
        setPosts(data.data);
      })
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  }, []);

  return <>{posts.email === 'test@tes.com' ? <div>{posts.email}</div> : ''}</>;
};
```

Comment: Since your server isn't running on your phone, it won't be able to connect to `localhost:5000`.

Comment: Either deploy it to some public server and use the correct IP address or URL, or run it locally, use your local IP and open the port to the network.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I'm running locally.